# What is the value and age of this pre-1967 Ricoh 35 mm camera?

Tags: 35mm, old-cameras, ricoh

I have a Ricoh 35 mm camera that has not been used since 1967. I am unable to find a value for it or an age. 
The body is stamped # 36530 and the lens is tagged # 70573.
Can anybody help me determine its age and value?

Comment: You might need to add some details. Ricoh made film cameras with M42 screw mounts as well as with the Pentax K-mount. Is there some model information such as KR-5 on it? Do you have unscrew the lens or is a bayonet style that you push a button and twist to release?

Comment: Could you maybe add a picture of the camera? This might help identification.

Comment: And what lens?  Each lens they made may have the same range of serial numbers.

Comment: It is a pretty old camera. It will be more helpful to identify if you can post a picture of the camera. From the info you provided, it's hard to guess. I'd suggest that you can go through Ricoh camera products website and see whether there's any info which can help you.
http://www.ricoh.com/r_dc/

Comment: wow that is a collectors' item.  you should give more details on it, and they're right it is better if you can upload a photo of it.

Comment: I think we need a picture or else this needs to be closed as just guessing.

Answer (score 3):

[Camerapedia index of Ricoh](http://camerapedia.wikia.com/wiki/index.php?search=ricoh&fulltext=Search) gives us a lot of pre-1967 models. Since you don't give us any model names or pictures you can check this page to see which one is yours.

Answer (score 0):

My GF and I have a modest collection of old cameras scattered about the house. I bought an Argus Rangefinder is superb condition with form fitted leather case and light meter also in a leather case all for ... $35 on ebay.

You might get lucky and yours could be super rare but there really are a lot of old cameras out there and few want them.